# Construct a container of derived pointers from a source container of base pointers

Tags: c++, boost, c++14

How can I efficiently return a vector of derived pointers from a vector of base pointers?

```
std::vector<const Base*> getb();
std::vector<const Derived*> getd()
{
  auto vb = getb(); /// I know for a fact all vb elements point to Derived
  return ...;
}
```

`Derived` does not inherit directly from `Base`

The objects exist in other containers that have process lifetime.

boost::ranges?

Comment: Since it's only pointers, you could use vector<void*> for both types, but I would consider it bad practice. Perhaps you could use a vector of shared_ptr, better. In any case you would need casting.

Answer (score 0):

> I know for a fact all vb elements point to Derived

The best course of action is to express that assertion with *types*. Why does `getb()` return a vector of base pointers in the first place, if you know a better type for the elements? Make it a vector of derived pointers from the start.

Failing that, you need to `dynamic_cast` each and every individual pointer in `vb` and put the result in another container. Other casts may or may not work.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would say that if you run into this problem, you should examine why, in your design, you need to do this step. Possibly there is something you could do differently to avoid this problem. Personally, I find it fishy, that you generate a container of `Base*` that each only point to `Derived` objects.

But if you want to do this, there are some possibilities how to go about this. If `B` is not a virtual base class of `D`, everywhere, you can use a `static_cast` instead of a `dynamic_cast`, due to [[expr.static.cast]/11](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#11) (in short, if you now that the `dynamic_cast` will work, you can also `static_cast`). This will save you the runtime check in the `dynamic_cast`.

**Conversion with memory overhead**

You basically create a second vector and copy all pointers over:

```cpp
const auto vb = get_b();
std::vector<const Derived*> ret;
ret.reserve(vb.size());
std::transform(cbegin(vb), cend(vb), std::back_inserter(ret), [](const Base* p) { return dynamic_cast<const Derived*>(p); });
return ret;
```

This is, in my opinion, the fastest and most concise way to do this only with the stl in C++14. I am not well versed in the capabilities of boost. If you can use some kind of transforming iterator, you could initialize `ret` directly from two iterators.

**No memory overhead, boilerplate code, slight access runtime overhead**

Wrap your `std::vector<const Base*>` in an own class that works like a vector and returns a `const Derived*` on access. With `dynamic_cast` this will have a slight runtime overhead when accessing, since it will have to do a check. If you can use a `static_cast` (as talked about above), this will not be the case. (You may have a very slight overhead due to the added level of indirection).

I really like this solution and personally would use it. I am not sure if boost has some kind of container adaptor, otherwise, you will have to write a bit of boilerplate code to have vector-like interface (you *could* inherit from `std::vector` and only overwrite `operator[]` and `at()`, but this has problems of its own since `std::vector` has no virtual methods, including its destructor!).

**No memory and no runtime overhead**

You would really like that, I guess^^. I don't think this is possible with an `std::vector`. For no runtime overhead, you would need to return an object that is really of type `std::vector<const Derived*>`. For no memory overhead you have to recycle the memory of the returned object of `get_b`.

But a `std::vector<T>` has no possibilty to relinquish ownership of its owned memory (except to another `std::vector<T>` on the same `T` through swap or move construction/assignment). Maybe you can do some fishy stuff with a custom allocator such that the underlying storage is not deleted when the vector is destroyed and you obtain it before destruction through `data()`. But this seems like a perfect way to obtain a memory leak. Especially since I don't really know how this works with capacity vs size.

Even if you get the underlying storage, you cannot use it, since you cannot construct a vector from a already allocated piece of memory. Of course here you can again do something evil with a custom allocator, but again this seems like a bad idea.

One could go around this problem by using `std::unique_ptr<T[]>` instead of `std::vector`. This is basically a compromise between `std::array` and `std::vector`. It holds an array of runtime size, but the size of this array is constant once it is allocated. Here you can obtain the storage with `release()` and construct a new `std::unique_ptr` from it without issue.

This brings us to the worst problem. The following code is not valid. You cannot even cast from a `Derived**` to a `Base**` (and lets not even talk about the other way round)

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<const Base*[]> base(static_cast<const Base**>(new Derived*[5]));
std::unique_ptr<const Derived*[]> dev(dynamic_cast<const Derived**>(base.release()));
```

I have no idea if there is some weird way of reinterpreting just the whole chunk of memory as pointers of other type. Even then if this in any way something sensible to do. So I see no way doing this variant.